# iOS App Transfer “Attempt to insert null object into an com.webobjects.foundation.NSMutableDictionary”

Tags: ios, app-store, app-transfer

When i try to transfer my App from one account to another i getting the following error . "**Attempt to insert null object into an com.webobjects.foundation.NSMutableDictionary**"

1. Both the account has same rights.

[image]

If any faced the same issue please let me know.
Thanks